# Qt Resource System (qrc), взять файл из другой вложенности

Tags: qt, resources

У меня есть директория с *.pri* файлом, в этой директории есть другая директория с другим *.pri* файлом, в котором есть ещё одна такая же директория, т.е. моя вложенность приобретает такой вид (прошу прощения если использовал некорректные символы для рисовки):

```
--- firlsLevel
---- secondLevel
------- thirdLevel
```

В корневом уровне есть файл ресурсов (**qrc**) и директория с изображениями. На втором и третьем уровнях мне необходимо взять одно из изображений. Как мне это сделать? Пробовал в .pri файлах писать так:

```
# Для secondLevel
RESOURCES += ../rsc.qrc 
# Для thirdLevel
RESOURCES += ../../rsc.qrc
```

Однако при компиляции появляются предупреждения (на 3к решил остановить сборку)
Благодарю за помощь.